# Trying to send CURL Command using VB.Net and HttpWebRequest - Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: json, vb.net, curl, httpwebrequest

I have been trying to send this CURL Command below, and tried a few examples out there but none of them work, as I need to send the username:password and not sure if this is a HEADER and also how to send the BODY of the GET Request. Just looking for a bit of an example which sends user:password as can't find one anywhere?

curl --data {"version":"1.1","method":"room_verify","params":{"account":{"type":"room","value":"0"}}} --user test:test http://ressrv.worldweb.com:8001/json_pos_generic/22

Here is my Code for this:

```
        Dim url As String = "http://ressrv.worldweb.com:8001/json_pos_generic/22"
    Dim wrq = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim postString As String = "{""version"":""1.1"",""method"":""room_verify"",""params"":{""account"":{""type"":""room"",""value"":""0""}}}"

        wrq.Method = "POST"
        wrq.ContentType = "application/json"
        wrq.ContentLength = postString.Length
        wrq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("test", "test")


    Dim wrqWriter As New StreamWriter(wrq.GetRequestStream())
    wrqWriter.Write(postString)
    wrqWriter.Close()

    Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(wrq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Any Help or Guidance would be much appreciated ...

Comment: Sorry I meant to say POST Request above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found an answer after 2 days of trying to get this sorted and although I used a slightly different bit of code, I think this was all down to not having my credentials converted to Base64 which I am now going to research into why this is required. I found this answer from another article here [Curl request equivalent in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496971/curl-request-equivalent-in-vb-net)

```
            Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
        Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse

        myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ressrv.worldweb.com:8001/json_pos_generic/22")

        myReq.Method = "POST"
        myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test:test")))
        Dim myData As String = "{""version"":""1.1"",""method"":""room_verify"",""params"":{""account"":{""type"":""room"",""value"":""0""}}}"
        myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)
        myResp = myReq.GetResponse
        Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
        Dim myText As String
        myText = myreader.ReadToEnd

        MsgBox(myText)
```

Thanks Anyway !!